# Download all the filters from tableau workbook

Tags: javascript, python, tableau-api

We built a tableau workbook and planning to move them to production soon. As part of deployment, we need to document all the filters used in the workbook. Is there any way, I can extract all the filters used in a workbook or configurations done in a workbook? Like an API or any other options to get all at once? Because, we have more than 100 sheets and its really difficult to open all, read and document it manually.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the Javascript API to query for all filters in the worksheet. 'Flights' is the sheet name

```
function getFiltersAsync() {
            // Get first worksheet in book
            var worksheet;
            var filtersVal='';
            var onSuccess = function (filters) {
                $("#lblFiltersCount").text("This worksheet has " + filters.length + " filter(s) associated with it.");
                $.each(filters, function (filter, i) {
                    // use .value property of each DataValue object
                    filtersVal += i.getFieldName() + ", ";
                    $("#lblFilterField").text(filtersVal);
                });
            };

            var onError = function (err) {
                alert("Whoops");
            };

            viz.getWorkbook().activateSheetAsync("Flights").then(function(sheet) {
                worksheet = sheet;
                worksheet.getFiltersAsync().then(onSuccess, onError);
            });
        }
```

Comment: Hi Mahesh, Thanks for your answer. Could you please explain how this works? I understand that its a javascript code, but where to execute this? And what is that "Flights", is it sheet name or workbook name?

Comment: for what it's worth if anyone comes across this and is looking for the answer to jeevags Q.   Mahesh's code is using the Javascript api.  That applies to the Viz when embed it in a web page using the 'Viz' class to embed your Viz.  see the official tutorial http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/samples/en-us/js_api/tutorial.htm

Answer (score 1):

Sharing the answer as anyone might require this in future.

http://community.tableau.com/message/358767#358767

Here is the code if anybody wishes to use this.

http://pastebin.com/bruVTSmN